# Implement Case milestone related list in salesforce lightning.

Tags: lightning-experience

I want to have Case milestone related list in Lightning which we see in Salesforce Classic.Can anybody has idea how to implement in lightning?

Comment: As specified in the help, it's only in Classic. You'd have to write your own code/component if you want this in Lightning.

Comment: As of now, it's not available in the related list but you can use the Milestone tracker. Did you check [this link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_entitlement_management_milestone_comp.htm).